# Local Homology of wedge sum of manifolds.

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology

I was told that for $n\geq1$ and two $n$-manifolds $M,N$ the local integral homology $H_n(M\vee N, M \vee N \setminus \{z\};\mathbb{Z})$ of the wedge sum $M \vee N$ at the 'glueing point' $z\in M \vee N$ was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Since $M,N$ locally look like $\mathbb{R}^n$ the statement is equivalent to showing that $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible the long exact sequence of reduced homology should give: $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \tilde{H}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\};\mathbb{Z})$.

Now for $n>1$, $\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}\,$ is homotopy equivalent to two disjoint copies of $S^{n-1}$ so the statement should follow from this. If $n=1$ however, $\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $4$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$ hence we should have $\tilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n \vee \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$, which would contradict the above statement.

Is this reasoning correct?